# SQLCMD in T-SQL with SQLCMDHEADERS -1 Not working in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

Been looking around, can't find an answer to my problem.
I am using a SQLCMD script, within T-SQl. So i start the script from SQL Server Management Studio and select the SQLCMD mode.

I use the variable SQLCMDHEADERS -1, like ":setvar SQLCMDHEADERS -1"
Next i run a lot of queries for output, to be stored into a file.

The header is still being printed however. Weird thing. Within in SQL Server 2012 this is working like how it should..

Anyone has a clue?